# C program not giving the correct output

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, per;
    printf("Enter marks in five subjects");
    scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", &m1, &m2, &m3, &m4, &m5);
    per=(m1+m2+m3+m4+m5)/500*100;
    if(per>=60)
        printf("First division");
    else if(per>=50)
        printf("Second division");
    else if(per>=40)
        printf("Third division");
    else
        printf("Fail");
}
```

Enter marks in five subjects 100, 100, 10, 50, 60
After giving this input printf showing Fail. But it will be First Division.
What is the problem in this program?

Comment: `per=(m1+m2+m3+m4+m5)/5`

Answer (score 3):

You are performing integer division

```
per=(m1+m2+m3+m4+m5)/500*100;
```

change it to

```
per = ((float)(m1 + m2 + m3 + m4 + m5)) / 500 * 100;
```

and since the maximum value of each `mn` is `100` so the maximum value of their sum is `500`, if it's less than `500` integer division yields always `0`.

Comment: If changing to float, you should also make the literals float: `500.0f * 100.0f`.

Answer (score 1):

Iharob is right - the problem is in making integer division  (i.e. int_operator / int_operator), and only after that multiplication works.
Modifications of Iharob’s solution can be also:

```
per = (m1 + m2 + m3 + m4 + m5) / 500.0 * 100; // now 500.0 is of double type
```

But assigning float (or double) values to integer variables is not always good idea because int has smaller range. So it is better to optimize your expression, e.g.:

```
per=(m1+m2+m3+m4+m5)/5;
```

Also you can change type of `per` to float (or double), or decide what you want from the result (rounding / separation integer part from remainder / just integer part)